# HDMI port on old raspberry pi physically hot when ran on batteries?

Tags: hardware, power, hdmi

I have a pi with a step-down and some batteries and for some reason the hdmi is the hottest part, even when I don't have a hdmi plugged in? Could somebody explain

Comment: If you check the cpu (or the metal square part on the board), that should be hot. It's just because the CPU is hot. If you are running something on it right now, that is one reason why it is getting hot. Why are you concerned about it though? Is there a project you need to do and it includes the HDMI?

Comment: I recommend detailing your question if you can.

Comment: Step-down transformer must be limited 5.1A.

Comment: @toyotaSupra This is not AC so no transformer.And a DC-DC step down PSU don't have to be limited to 5.1A. Your answer is just confused.

Comment: Sorry my mistaken. I read step-down. Thanks.